# Worklight 6.1 previous versions

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I need to build my project with Worklight version **6.1.0.02.20141216-0421**, but I didn't find it. Please who has this version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an extremely old build and unless this build was an official iFix release - it will no longer exist. So, if you are an IBM customer you can look for this build number in the IBM Fix Central website.

Note however that you should always use the latest available iFix release... and not a build from more than two years ago, especially for production. If you will request official support, you will be told to use the latest build.

Comment: Thanks for your support ! I found it in the IBM Fix Central website.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must have this specific build, you can find it [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/quickorder?parent=ibm%7EOther%20software&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20Worklight%20Consumer%20Edition&release=6.1.0.2&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=6.1.0.2-WCE-IF201412160421&includeRequisites=1&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http&source=fc) if you use Worklight Consumer Edition, or [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/quickorder?parent=ibm%7EOther%20software&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20Worklight%20Enterprise%20Edition&release=6.1.0.2&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=6.1.0.2-WEE-IF201412160421&includeRequisites=1&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http&source=fc) if you use Worklight Enterprise Edition, if you are an IBM customer with a valid support entitlement.

However, if there isn't a very specific reason that you absolutely must have this specific build, I strongly agree with Idan's answer that you should use the most recent iFix build available on IBM Fix Central.  As of right now, the latest build contains fixes for 93 separate APARs that are not contained in the build you are asking about (from more than 2 years ago).